# <div> figures in search rendering issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

SO I have some code where jQuery and CSS are made to create a close icon after clicking the search icon. It uses the same div elements since it is supposed to animate itself (it doesn't in our case). As I was working (without affecting anything that has to do with the following search icon), I realized one of the divs height is out of place. If you view the CSS, you see that there are two divs with class of 'search2' and one of them is at an improper height or scale. I tried resizing the window and it does not go away.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwg7t.png)

So I have a search icon with this code:

```js
function toggleSearch(){
    $('.mobile-search-button').toggleClass('expand');
}
```

```css
.mobile-search-button {
 position: absolute;
 top: 5px;
 right: 15px;
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
 border: none;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.mobile-search-button * {
 position: relative;
 bottom: 4px;
 left: 1px;
}

.search1 {
 width: 12px;
 height: 12px;
 border: 2px solid black;
 border-radius: 100px;
}
.search2 {
 width: 10px;
 height: 2px;
 background: black;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(5px,-5px);
 -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(5px,-5px);
 transform: rotate(45deg) translate(5px,-5px);
}
.search3 {
 opacity: 0;
}
.mobile-search-button .search1 {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(5px,-5px) scale(1.75);
 -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(5px,-5px) scale(1.75);
 transform: rotate(45deg) translate(5px,-5px) scale(1.75);
}
.mobile-search-button .search2 {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(19px,-9px) scale(1.75);
 -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(19px,-9px) scale(1.75);
 transform: rotate(45deg) translate(19px,-9px) scale(1.75);
}
.mobile-search-button.expand .search1 {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(9px,-10px) scale(5);
 -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(9px,-10px) scale(5);
 transform: rotate(45deg) translate(9px,-10px) scale(5);
 opacity: 0;
}
.mobile-search-button.expand .search2 {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(9px,-9px) scale(1.75) scaleX(2);
 -ms-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(9px,-9px) scale(1.75) scaleX(2);
 transform: rotate(45deg) translate(9px,-9px) scale(1.75) scaleX(2);
}
.mobile-search-button.expand .search3 {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(10px,7px) scale(1.75) scaleX(2);
 -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(10px,7px) scale(1.75) scaleX(2);
 transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(10px,7px) scale(1.75) scaleX(2);
 opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="toggleSearch();" class="mobile-search-button" title="Search">
   <div class="search1"></div>
   <div class="search2"></div>
   <div class="search2 search3"></div>
  </button>
```

UPDATE: I changed the height of div.search2 from 2px to 1.75px and it seems to work

Comment: Looks fine to me. What do you mean one has an improper height or scale? can you draw a picture or something of what you're expecting to see or point it out another way?

Comment: I just tested it in Firefox and it worked, but I sent this question while I was in chrome. When you click the search icon in the snippet, you should get a close icon you should end up with two bars with equal height intersecting each other but one if them has a bigger height. I edited the post by taking a screen clipping

Comment: Hmm. looks ok to me in chrome, safari, and firefox on a mac.

Comment: I changed the height for all '.search2' elements from 2px to 1.75px and things look good.

Answer (score 0):

I think the CSS could be done simpler.

```js
function toggleSearch() {
  $('.mobile-search-button').toggleClass('expand');
}
```

```css
.mobile-search-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 15px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
}

.search1,
.search2 {
  background: black;
  height: 36px;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -18px 0 0 -2px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 200ms;
  top: 50%;
  width: 4px;
}

.search1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.search2 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.expand .search2 {
  background: #dddddd;
  border: 4px solid black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  left: 7px;
  margin: 0;
  top: 6px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="toggleSearch();" class="mobile-search-button" title="Search">
        <div class="search1"></div>
        <div class="search2"></div>
</button>
```